# AES extra argument 'padding' in call? swift2

Tags: ios, encryption, swift2, aes, cryptoswift

I make extension to generate function to encrypt and decrypt with AES like this :

```
import cryptoswift

extension String {
func aesEncrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String{
    let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let enc = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode:.CBC).encrypt(data!.arrayOfBytes(), padding: PKCS7())
    let encData = NSData(bytes: enc, length: Int(enc.count))
    let base64String: String = encData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0));
    let result = String(base64String)
    return result
}

func aesDecrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let dec = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode:.CBC).decrypt(data!.arrayOfBytes(), padding: PKCS7())
    let decData = NSData(bytes: dec, length: Int(dec.count))
    let result = NSString(data: decData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return String(result!)
}
}
```

but both aesEncrypt and aesDecrypt have error extra argument 'padding' in call in these line:

```
let enc = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode:.CBC).encrypt(data!.arrayOfBytes(), padding: PKCS7())
```

and

```
let dec = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode:.CBC).decrypt(data!.arrayOfBytes(), padding: PKCS7())
```

How to repair these error?

Update:
I am using new way to get aes encryption:

```
let langinput = "us"
let aes = try AES(key: key, iv: iv) // aes128
let langencrypted = try aes.encrypt(langinput.utf8.map({$0}))
let encData = NSData(bytes: langencrypted, length: Int(langencrypted.count))
let base64String: String = encData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0));
let aes_encrypt_result = String(base64String)
```

Comment: it is use cryptoswift aes

Comment: the error is extra argument 'padding' in call

Comment: the error is in the func aesEncrypt and func aesDecrypt.

Comment: What is the Error message?

Comment: Extra argument 'padding' in call

Comment: did my update code correct?

Comment: Don't use CryptoSwift, it is just a scam to get developers to use poor encryption. Why I have no idea.

Comment: so where I can I got aes encryption sample use Apple's Common Crypto?

Comment: RNCryptor did not need iv? only key as password?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

AES is a block cipher meaning the data must be a multiple of block size (AES 16-bytes) so padding bytes need to be added during encryption and removed during decryption.

Use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it uses Apple's Common Crypto that is FIPS 140 certified and uses the hardware encryption engine. It provided authenticated AES encryption and if needed password derivation. It is well  vetted. Other than that there are several Swift AES implementations on SO.

RNCryptor handles the iv for you prepending it to the encrypted data along with other information. See [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec). It is not a good choice if you need to interoperate with another implementation.